# How do I print a hash of hash to a table in an ASCII file?

Tags: ruby, hashtable

I am trying to print a hash of hash to a table in a log file in ASCII format. I have a hash, where its values are again a hash and its value is a list:

```
irb(main):057:0> h = {  
irb(main):058:1* 'mode1' => {
irb(main):059:2*    'name1' => [2, 4],
irb(main):060:2*    'name2' => [54, 65]
irb(main):061:2>    },
irb(main):062:1*  'mode2' => {
irb(main):063:2*     'name4' => [3, 0],
irb(main):064:2*     'name3' => [2, 1]
irb(main):065:2>     },
irb(main):066:1*  'mode3' => {
irb(main):067:2*     'xys' => [100, 28]
irb(main):068:2>     }
irb(main):069:1>  }
```

I want it to be printed as:

```
**************************************************************************************
| No    |       Mode Name       |     Sub Name         | Value 1       |   Value 2   |
**************************************************************************************
|   1   |       mode1           |     name1            |     2         |      4      |
|       |                       |     name2            |     54        |      65     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2   |       mode2           |     name4            |     3         |      0      |
|       |                       |     name3            |     2         |      1      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   3   |       mode3           |     xys              |     100       |      28     |
**************************************************************************************
```

1. Is there an easy way to achieve this?
2. I am trying out my own way using `printf`, but I am not able to figure out how to center-justify, using a `hash.each` block and I am stuck when the inner hash has multiple keys. I don't need to print first and second columns.

I am using `ruby 1.8.6 (2009-08-04 patchlevel 383)`.

Comment: Can you show what you've attempted?

Comment: https://github.com/visionmedia/terminal-table

Comment: or https://github.com/aptinio/text-table

Comment: @DaveNewton: Thanks a ton for the gem. I used it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on "[What is the “right” way to iterate through an array in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/691798/1930331)":

```
puts "*" * <number of asterisks>
puts "|\tNo\t|\tMode\t|..."
puts "*" * <number of asterisks>

number = 1
for mode in h.keys.sort
    first = true
    for subkey in mode.keys.sort
        if first
            puts "|\t#{number.inspect}\t|\t#{h[mode].inspect}\t|\t#{subkey.inspect}\t|..."
            first = false
        else
            puts "|\t\t|\t\t|\t#{subkey.inspect}\t|..."
        end
        puts "-" * <number of dashes>
    end
    number += 1
end
```

Comment: It'd be better to not reinvent a wheel. Take advantage of one of the existing gems mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @theTinMan: Thanks. I used one of the gems available for this purpose.