# Ruby display array values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am not a ruby developer. This is the first time I am looking into the code. I want to build a dynamic table for which I have managed below code. However, I am not able to display all the contents of the array except for the first and the last values. How do I display all the values?

Thanks for your help!!

```
<style>table, td, th{border:1px solid white;}td{padding:5px;}th{background-color:#E0E6EB;color:black;}</style>
<div>
<table border=2>
<tr>
  <th width="250px"><B><p style="text-align: center">Name</p></B></th>
<th width="120px"><B><p style="text-align: center">Number</p></B></th>
<th width="60px"><B><p style="text-align: center">Status</p></B></th>
<th width="155px"><B><p style="text-align: center">Product Type</p></B></th>
<th width="60px"><B><p style="text-align: center">Source</p></B></th>
</tr>
  <% tempTickets = @subject.PersonAccounts.sorted_by(field("title").in_descending_order) %>  
  <% cnt = tempTickets.length %>
  <% tempTickets.each do |ticket| %>
<div>
<tr>
  <td><%= ticket['perfinaccnt-accountname'].first %></td>
<td><%= ticket['perfinaccnt-accountnumber'].first %></td>
<td><%= ticket['perfinaccnt-accountstatus'].first %></td>
<td><%= ticket['perfinaccnt-producttype'].first %></td>
<td><%= ticket['perfinaccnt-accountsrcsystem'].first %></td>
</tr>
</div>
<div>
<tr>
  <td><%= ticket['perfinaccnt-accountname'].last %></td>
<td><%= ticket['perfinaccnt-accountnumber'].last %></td>
<td><%= ticket['perfinaccnt-accountstatus'].last %></td>
<td><%= ticket['perfinaccnt-producttype'].last %></td>
<td><%= ticket['perfinaccnt-accountsrcsystem'].last %></td>
</tr>
</div>

  <% end %>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know the attributes of the object?

Comment: I am not sure at all about the attributes. Since, I am able to display first and last elements of the array. how do I loop through it?

Comment: You're already looping through tempTickets using each method.

Comment: Is this what you looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310634/what-is-the-right-way-to-iterate-through-an-array-in-ruby

Comment: Based on the loop count, can I change the index value in the below code?  ticket['perfinaccnt-accountname'].<index>

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with three nested loops:

```
<%= tempTickets.each do |ticket|
    [
      'perfinaccnt-accountname',
      'perfinaccnt-accountnumber',
      'perfinaccnt-accountstatus',
      'perfinaccnt-producttype',
      'perfinaccnt-accountsrcsystem'
    ].each do |f|
        ticket[f].each do |tf|
            puts "<td>tf</td>";
        end if ticket[f]
    end 
end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code - However, the code is printing below text outside the table.  "[#<Entity:0x69b60a95 @entity=#<Java::ComVivisimoGelatoEntityResultset::SortedEntity:0x1abe9cdf>, @resolver=#<InstrumentationProxy:0x17e29ce0 @jmx_wrapper=#<JMXWrapper:0xeccd5d5d @mbean_store=#<MBeanStore:0x6b9e402e @mbean_store={}>, "

Comment: I can't really help you there without knowing what the data is. The text you are seeing is most likely due to one of the fields being a class thats not meant to be printed directly.

Comment: Then what could be the option to print a class?

Comment: Check the object.class would do that.

Comment: In my original code, ticket['perfinaccnt-accountname'].class is showing me the value as Array, and printing ticket['perfinaccnt-accountname'] gave me the list of values with comma separation enclosed within []

Comment: It depends on what the class is - there is no easy answer there. Ruby automatically calls `to_s` on a class when pass it to `puts` (print).

The class name suggests its part of IBM's Vivisimo Velocity Platform. So you might want to look in the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the data structure here but you could check it by doing an #inspect to tempTickets and all the subsequent objects. From the looks of it "ticket['perfinaccnt-accountname']" is actually an array
and as such you can just loop through it. Not the fastest way to do it but it should work to just do a nested loop.

```
<style>table, td, th{border:1px solid white;}td{padding:5px;}th{background-color:#E0E6EB;color:black;}</style>
<div>
<table border=2>
<tr>
  <th width="250px"><B><p style="text-align: center">Name</p></B></th>
<th width="120px"><B><p style="text-align: center">Number</p></B></th>
<th width="60px"><B><p style="text-align: center">Status</p></B></th>
<th width="155px"><B><p style="text-align: center">Product Type</p></B></th>
<th width="60px"><B><p style="text-align: center">Source</p></B></th>
</tr>
  <% tempTickets = @subject.PersonAccounts.sorted_by(field("title").in_descending_order) %>
  <% cnt = tempTickets.length %>
  <% tempTickets.each do |ticket| %>
  <div><tr>
    <%  ticket.each do |k,v|
          v.each do |col| %>
            <td><%= col %></td>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
  </tr></div>
  <% end %>
</table>
</div>
```