# Unable to split the statement into multiple lines from an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, string, split

I want to split the statement array into 2 different lines in RUBY:

```
statement = ["Statement1", "Statement2"]
```

This is how I am splitting the array

```
result = statement.split(", ")
```

The output what I want is:

```
Statement1
Statement2
```

But I am getting the error as:

```
undefined method `split' for ["Statement1", "Statement2"]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

Can someone please help me? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: split is not defined for lists. It is defined only for strings.

Comment: Then what should i use to split it into 2 different lines?

Comment: I am really sorry for giving you half question. I want this in Ruby

Comment: Okay. I deleted my answer then.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/uW57E8, you do not need to split the items, you need to *access* them with indices, or using `.first`/`.last`. A list is already split, why split it again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "right" way to iterate through an array in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310634/what-is-the-right-way-to-iterate-through-an-array-in-ruby)

Comment: This question makes no sense. An array has no lines. You cannot split it into lines because the idea of "line" doesn't even make sense in the context of arrays. Lines are related to text, not arrays.

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over the array.

```
stmtAry = ["Statement1", "Statement2"]
stmtAry.each{|i| puts i}
```

You can directly output each statement without iterating on them if you don't need any other operation other than printing out.

```
stmtAry = ["Statement1", "Statement2"]
puts stmtAry
```

Both codes provides the same output:

Output:

```
Statement1 
Statement2
```

Comment: [`IO#puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-i-puts) with an `Array` will already put each element on its own line without the need to iterate using `#each`.

Comment: @engineersmnky I update the answer according to your comment

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't go much shorter :

```
puts statement
# Statement1
# Statement2
```

From the [`puts` documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-puts) :

> If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line.

If you want to get just one string from your array, you could use [Array#join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join), which is the opposite of [String#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) :

```
statement.join("\n")
```

It returns one string :

```
"Statement1\nStatement2"
```

when displayed with puts :

```
Statement1
Statement2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are trying call `split` method of Array class but Array class doesn't have this method.

You can check whether method is existed in calling class or not by using this way

```
statement = ["Statement1", "Statement2"]
statement.methods
[:inspect, :to_s, :to_a, :to_h, :to_ary, :frozen?, :==, :eql?, :hash, :[], :[]=, :at, :fetch, :first, :last, :concat, :<<, :push, :pop, :shift, :unshift, :insert, :each, :each_index, :reverse_each, :length, :size, :empty?, :find_index, :index, :rindex, :join, :reverse, :reverse!, :rotate, :rotate!, :sort, :sort!, :sort_by!, :collect, :collect!, :map, :map!, :select, :select!, :keep_if, :values_at, :delete, :delete_at, :delete_if, :reject, :reject!, :zip, :transpose, :replace, :clear, :fill, :include?, :<=>, :slice, :slice!, :assoc, :rassoc, :+, :*, :-, :&, :|, :uniq, :uniq!, :compact, :compact!, :flatten, :flatten!, :count, :shuffle!, :shuffle, :sample, :cycle, :permutation, :combination, :repeated_permutation, :repeated_combination, :product, :take, :take_while, :drop, :drop_while, :bsearch, :any?, :pack, :entries, :sort_by, :grep, :find, :detect, :find_all, :flat_map, :collect_concat, :inject, :reduce, :partition, :group_by, :all?, :one?, :none?, :min, :max, :minmax, :min_by, :max_by, :minmax_by, :member?, :each_with_index, :each_entry, :each_slice, :each_cons, :each_with_object, :chunk, :slice_before, :slice_after, :slice_when, :lazy, :nil?, :===, :=~, :!~, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :itself, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :trust, :freeze, :methods, :singleton_methods, :protected_methods, :private_methods, :public_methods, :instance_variables, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set, :instance_variable_defined?, :remove_instance_variable, :instance_of?, :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :send, :public_send, :respond_to?, :extend, :display, :method, :public_method, :singleton_method, :define_singleton_method, :object_id, :to_enum, :enum_for, :equal?, :!, :!=, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :__send__, :__id__]
```

So there is no `split`  method in this above response that's why your are getting this error.

So if you face any issue in future like this and it would help you.

Comment: you could also use `Array.public_method_defined?(:split) #=> false` this will tell you if that class or an instance of that class has a method defined by name (excludes private and protected methods).