# Class name in html.erb file separated

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, erb

I have an `if` statement inside a loop to change a variable (named var_class) for a class name. How can I make it continuous string?

Here is the code:

```
<% j = 0%>
<% @question.each do |index| %>
<% var_class = ""%>
   <% j == 0 ? var_class = "tab-pane fade active show" : var_class = "tab-pane fade" %>
   <div class=<%=var_class %> style='height: 444px; overflow-y: auto;' id=<%="question#{j+=1}"%>>
```

But when i viewed the html in chrome inspect, it's not included as a continuous string but instead is separated when there is space. Like such:

```
class= "tab-pane" fade active show
```

but i want it to be

```
class = "tab-pane fade active show"
```

I've tried `<div class=<%=#{var_class} %>` and `<div class=<%="var_class" %>` and derivatives of that. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're missing the quotes of class and id attributes.

```
<div class='<%=var_class %>' style='height: 444px; overflow-y: auto;' id='<%="question#{j+=1}"%>'>
```

Answer (score 2):

Messias' answer is the basics of it. Without the quotes around the string, the DOM is stopping the classes when it hits a space. It thinks the other items are attributes on the `div` tag.

In a best-practices kind of way, we typically want to avoid local assigns (where you set a variable) in the rails view. This really wants to be a helper or a decorator (if you really need that level of functionality and testability).

[The following is pseudo code that I haven't tested, so there may be some minor errors]

In your ERB view:

```
<% @questions.each do |index| %>
  <div class="<%= classy(index) %>" id="[TBD see below]">
<% end %>
```

I'd suggest finding a more semantic HTML tag than `div` if possible. Iterators (.each) tend to be a list of objects, so perhaps a UL (unordered list) or OL (ordered list) with LIs inside might be a better choice. ULs give you buttons and OLs give you numbers by default, but those can be changed.

You also probably want to avoid the # sign in a ID name, as you would call an ID in a css file with #name. So #name#2 will likely give you some unexpected and messy results in the DOM. You likely want to use `each_ with _index` to get both the array and the index value. Pretty good explanation of the differences here: [What is the "right" way to iterate through an array in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310634/what-is-the-right-way-to-iterate-through-an-array-in-ruby)

```
<ul class="questions">
<% @questions.each_with_index do |question,index| %>
  <li class="<%= classy(question, index) %>" id="question_<%= index %>">
    [CONTENT]
  </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

The helper method in whatever_helper.rb (matching the class name or application if site wide):

```
def classy(question, index)
  if index == 0
    "tab-pane fade active show"
  else
    "tab-pane fade"
  end
end
```

And while we're at it, lets get presentation markup out of the view. In your CSS file:

```
.tab-pane.fade {
  height: 444px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

If you're trying to achieve something different, let us know. This was my best guess based on reading the question and code.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby you can use `Enumerable#each_with_index` to iterate through a collection with an index:

```
<% @question.each_with_index do |value, index| %>

<% end %>

<% end %>
```

In general in Ruby if you are using `.each` or any iterator with an external mutating variable you are doing it wrong.

You can also clean up the view by using `content_tag`:

```
<% @question.each_with_index do |value, index| %>
  <% 
      classes = ["tab-pane", "fade"] 
      classes = classes + ["active", "show"] if index == 0
  %>
  <%= content_tag :div, class: classes, id: "question#{index+1}" do %>

  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The same approach can be used with straight ERB inpolation if you just join an array of classes:

```
<div class="<%= classes.join(" ")%>" ...
```