# How can I iterate over an array of hashes and form new one

Tags: ruby, loops

I have a call to Companies House API and response I get from API is an array of hashes.

```
companies = {
 "total_results" => 2, 
 "items" => [{
  "title" => "First company",
  "date_of_creation" => "2016-11-09",
  "company_type" => "ltd",
  "company_number" => "10471071323",
  "company_status" => "active"
 }, 
 {
  "title" => "Second company",
  "date_of_creation" => "2016-11-09",
  "company_type" => "ltd",
  "company_number" => "1047107132",
  "company_status" => "active"
 }]
}
```

How I can iterate over companies and get a result similar to:

```
[{
  title: "First company",
  company_number: "10471071323"
},
{
  title: "Second company",
  company_number: "1047107132"
}]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the "right" way to iterate through an array in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310634/what-is-the-right-way-to-iterate-through-an-array-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map) which will iterate through the elements in an array and return a new array:

```rb
companies["items"].map do |c| 
  {
    title: c['title'],
    company_number: c['company_number'] 
  }
end
 => [
  {:title=>"First company", :company_number=>"10471071323"},
  {:title=>"Second company", :company_number=>"1047107132"}
]
```

Comment: Thanks @Fernando, this worked out for me. I have as well added #dig method to avoid NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

```rb
companies.map { |company| company.slice('title', 'company_number').symbolize_keys }
```

This should do the trick.

If you're not using Rails (or, more specifically, ActiveSupport), then `symbolize_keys` won't be available. In this case, you'd have to go for a more standard-Ruby approach:

```rb
companies.map do |company|
  { title: company["title"], company_number: company["company_number"] }
end
```

Comment: `slice` keeps the string keys.

Comment: Fair enough. If Rails is being used, you can add `symbolize_keys`: `companies.map { |company| company.slice('title', 'company_number').symbolize_keys }`

Comment: @ClemensKofler: It may be useful to update your original answer to include that alternate option, and a better explanation of when one is useful compared to the others.

Answer (score 0):

The answers are totally correct; but you should be made aware that what you’re looking at from companies house is not just an array of hashes - it’s a valid JsonApi response.

You might find your job easier if you’re using a gem which is aware of JsonApi specs, or if you’re just approaching it as that kind of data.

Have a look at the ruby implementations of https://jsonapi.org/implementations/

Or ActiveModelSerializer for ways to not only reform your hashes but deserialise this very structured data into ruby objects.

But like I say, if all you’re looking for is a quick way to reform the data as you describe. The above answers are perfect.